# hcitool connection drop

Tags: linux, bluetooth

I create a connection with hcitool:

```
hcitool cc 00:11:22:...
```

And then list all connections that exist at the moment:

```
hcitool con
```

The first time I issue this command, the connection I just created is listed. If I issue the command again, no connection is listed. I searched around and found that the kernel closes the connection in 1-2 sec and I have to issue "l2ping" in order to keep the connection alive.
I also wrote some code that creates a connection and then reads `RSSI` in a loop (with intervals between the reads), but the connection still failed in a couple of seconds or so, Is there a way to disable this kernel's behavior (if it is the kernel)? Or somehow to disable it in code or at least avoid it?

Comment: I don't know the exact solution, but I believe your connection is being killed due to another piece of the bt stack that is reacting to the connection event and expecting authentication to happen.  The connection gets killed if auth doesn't happen within a few seconds.  You can try modifying the authentication modes, or pair your device so auth can succeed.

Comment: Though not sure , maybe hcitool creates l2cap connection and query for SDP.if any services are present which local device also supports, a connection will be made and Bluetooth link would be active else after SDP, it will disconnect the channel, you can try with pairing first and then using hcitool